# Formula defaults to hh:mm despite number format HH:mm

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

hh:mm[image]

I have a sheet. I want the header to show the mean value of each column.
`SUBTOTAL(101, range)` ignores hidden rows, plus I want to display the mean end time in the same 24h time format as the start time. I just don't see why the same formula yields a different format in a different column.

I expected that using HH instead of hh would yield a 24-hour time format, but no.
HH:mm[image]

Here is an example of my damage: [My Dumb Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EiyWRXQFQ0qzBlqzz25rz1aLFewXHJggb-YINbZFiYQ/)

Date format: same result.

Expected: HH:mm for 24-hour times.
Observed: 14:00 shows as 2:00.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying times for column E includes a date  for some rows, which when averaged creates a new date time, whose time corresponds to `02:14` in 24h format:

| Col E + Subtotal | Underlying data number | Underlying data full date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **02:14** | **32,397.09** | **11/09/1988 02:14:18** |
| 15:59 | 0.67 | 30/12/1899 15:59:49 |
| 19:12 | 45,353.80 | 02/03/2024 19:12:20 |
| 14:45 | 45,354.62 | 03/03/2024 14:45:51 |
| 13:45 | 45,355.57 | 04/03/2024 13:45:49 |
| 15:03 | 45,356.63 | 05/03/2024 15:03:25 |
| 16:18 | 45,357.68 | 06/03/2024 16:18:52 |
| 16:34 | 0.69 | 30/12/1899 16:34:00 |